# LevelDB Download Issues

Tags: database, leveldb

Can anybody help me, from where I can download LevelDB for Java-Windows because I found it is [empty](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/downloads/list)? And any link how to install and run will be helpful to me.

Comment: git clone https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/ and build it.

Comment: @cHao, I checked that page but download page is empty.

Comment: That's cause you don't download it.  You clone it, with git.  There is no release yet, so unless you wanna mess around with Git and Visual Studio, you'll have to pray someone else feels like putting together a prepackaged Windows build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly this is a Java port of LevelDB, but I don't know if it's any good: https://github.com/dain/leveldb

There is also a JNI port: https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni

The main thing to point out is that LevelDB is not available as a distributable (jar, dll, lib, etc.), so you have to build it yourself (which is not hard).